How did Hugh Campbell Sr.'s clothes go through the walls
In The Boys S04E05, Hugh Sr. gets the power to phase through walls. There's this scene where he runs through a wall holding a human heart. The heart doesn't go through, but his clothes go through just fine. Is there any explanation as to how his clothes were able to go through walls?


This seems like an especially big oversight if you consider that the fact that the invisible guy has to be naked in order to be invisible is an explicit plot point.

In the Marvel universe, superheroes often exert an aura that extends a few cm out from their body. This is largely because these comics are intended for children and nude characters roaming around the place would not be very PC
